# Able to use custom variables in page.html.twig but not in menu.html.twig

Tags: 8, hooks, theming

I have a module setting config variables which I'm trying to display in a twig template. When I use

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
    $variables['facebook'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('facebook', 'No username');
    $variables['twitter'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('twitter', 'No username');
    $variables['instagram'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('instagram', 'No username');
    $variables['youtube'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('youtube', 'No username');              
}
```

I'm able to display the variables in my page.html.twig template by invoking

```
{{ facebook }}{{ twitter }}{{ instagram }}{{ youtube }}
```

However I'd like menu.html.twig to invoke it. Even when adding a preprocess hook for menu like so

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables){
    $variables['facebook'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('facebook', 'No username');
    $variables['twitter'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('twitter', 'No username');
    $variables['instagram'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('instagram', 'No username');
    $variables['youtube'] = \Drupal::config('social.settings')->get('youtube', 'No username');              
}
```

menu.html.twig produces nothing when invoking

```
{{ facebook }}{{ twitter }}{{ instagram }}{{ youtube }}
```

I know menu.html.twig is being used because I can make changes to it and the changes will appear. I also know that mytheme_preprocess_menu is being called because drupal_set_message works from it.
However {{ dump() }} from menu.html.twig is not displaying anything on the page.

Comment: This should work. Have you checked that both the preprocess function and the custom template are used?

Comment: If you don't use a debugger tool then the die function can be used to make sure the preprocess function is used, and you can insert some reason text in the template to make sure it is used.

Comment: P.S. you should pass the `\Drupal::config(...)` result to a variable.

Comment: I know that the function is being called because I added drupal_set_message to it and it's able to display the variables just fine.

Comment: Did you check that the template file is used?

Comment: Tes. I added random text to menu.html.twig and it shows up just fine

Comment: Also {{ dump() }} from menu.html.twig does not show anything

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu theme is declared using the variables key ([see doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/drupal_common_theme/8.2.x)).

That means that only the keys present in the variables array can be passed to the template.

Any custom variable needs to be first added using hook_theme_registery_alter

Comment: I'm unable to find any reference to hook_theme_alter. Do you mean hook_theme_registry_alter()?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: I'm not having any luck. Do I add the variables to hook_theme_registry_alter in the same way as I did in mytheme_preprocess_menu? Or is there another technique?

Comment: or does the menu not have access to the variables array from twig? I did check in the synchronization settings and the variables do appear there. Also after performing dump() on menu.html.twig only menu variables appear to be available.